# How to manage password hashing?

Tags: java, hash, network-programming, passwords

I'm making a multiplayer game with client-server architecture and I was wondering what the exact process is for hashing passwords for the logging in part. The first time a player logs in, should he send the password over the network and then have the server hash it (and store the hash)? If so, what is the modern recommendation for hashing (MD5, SHA, etc), and how do I implement this in Java?

Comment: Definitely not MD5. If the password is transmitted, it's not safe if a rogue server or network sniffer is in play. Hash password, send it, hash again on their side. Preferably with a salt per-server.

Comment: MD5 and SHA are not secure enough. Use bcrypt or PBKDF2.

Comment: @GergoErdosi For the purposes of a game, SHA can be sufficient. Depends on the game and what other risks exist, though.

Comment: @hexafraction I've also heard it's not the best...What other options are there besides SHA-256? I'm very new to the concept of hashing.

Comment: What's the difference between them?

Comment: @NathanielD.Hoffman Hashing is just a one-way, non-reversible, deterministic transformation. Alternatives include the standards such as SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512, oddball ones like Whirlpool, and multi-level ones such as PBKDF2. SHA is fairly easy to compute as a hash (the slower a hash is to compute, the slower it is to bruteforce). PBKDF is much slower (on the order of maybe 1000 hashes/sec if I'm not mistaken) but equally slow to bruteforce.

Comment: @hexafraction So basically, the first login, the user enters a password, then I hash it, send that to the server, and it hashes it again and stores it? What happens when the user tries to login again though? Will the typed password be hashed the same on the client, no matter what computer is being used?

Comment: @NathanielD.Hoffman Yes, assuming the client's hashing code (part of Java) is not broken. My answer lays it out a bit better than comments as it's not constrained by a 500-character limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hashing is just a one-way, non-reversible, deterministic transformation. This means that given an input string(in this case, password), one can easily compute a hash, and hashing the same input string over and over again will give the same hash, even on different machines, as long as the same rules are used.

Hashing strings that are even *minutely* different will give a massively different hash due to the "avalanche effect". You cannot predict the password from the hash, nor can you pick a password that matches a hash, except on broken algorithms such as MD5.

MD5 and SHA1 should not be used.

Alternatives include the standards such as SHA256, SHA384, and SHA512, oddball ones like Whirlpool, and multi-level ones such as PBKDF2. SHA is fairly easy to compute as a hash (the slower a hash is to compute, the slower it is to bruteforce). PBKDF is much slower (on the order of maybe 1000 hashes/sec if I'm not mistaken) but equally slow to bruteforce.

If the password is transmitted, it's not safe if a rogue server or network sniffer is in play. I recommend hashing the password, sending it over the wire, and hashing it again on the server side, preferably with a salt per-server. If the initial hash is computed using username concatenated with password, that would be equally nice for security.

So, if H(X) is the hash of X, the following will occur:

1. At login, client calculates H(username + password)
2. Client sends username and this hash over the wire. Even knowing the username there's no security risk of getting the password; it still must be bruteforced and the username precludes a kind of attack using a database called a *rainbow table*
3. Server hashes the hash it was sent with a salt and stores it to the logon database if the user is a new user, or compares it to the existing entry if it is not a new user. (that is, it stores H(salt + H(username + password)). H(username + password) is, of course, provided by the client. The salt should be different for every server, but not change on a given server. This can be a setting in a server configuration file set by the admin.